# Nested Master Pages in ASP.NET results in missing controls!

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have the following Hierarchy:

MainMasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainAdmin.master.cs" Inherits="MyWebsite.Admin.MainAdmin" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="MainMenu_Div" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainMenu" runat="server"/>
</div>

<div id="ContentArea_Div" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentArea" runat="server"/>
</div>
</form>
```

TemplateMasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/MasterPages/MainAdmin.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TemplateMasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MyWebsite.Admin.TemplateMasterPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentArea" runat="server">
    <div id="InputControls_Div" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="InputControls" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Submit_Btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            onclick="Submit_Btn_Click" />
    </div>


    <div id="AfterSubmission_Div" runat="server" visible="False">
    <asp:Button ID="AnotherBtn" runat="server" CssClass="linkLookingButton" 
        onclick="AnotherBtn_Click" />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

TemplateMasterPage (Code Behind)

```
public partial class TemplateMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string BtnText
    {
        get { return AnotherBtn.Text; } //AnotherBtndoesn't exist in the current context
        set { AnotherBtn.Text = value; } //AnotherBtndoesn't exist in the current context
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Submit_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Submit_Btn.Enabled = false; //Submit_Btn doesn't exist in the current context

        InputControls_Div.Visible = false; //InputControls_Div doesn't exist in the current context
        AfterSubmission_Div.Visible = true; //AfterSubmission_Div doesn't exist in the current context
    }
```

I commented the errors in my Code Behind sample .. this is used to work before using Nested Master Pages!

Comment: How do the [`@ Master` directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228176.aspx) look like?

Comment: I've added the directives .. please check them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just built a website based on your code fragments.

Some thoughts on it:

- Your class is named `TemplatePage` in code behind but refered as `TemplateMasterPage`.
- There *is* no control `AnotherBtn`. There is `Submit_Btn` only.
- There *is* no control `Btn`. There is `Submit_Btn` only.
- I get *no* errors on `InputControls_Div` or `AfterSubmission_Div`.

So all I can say, that your compiler is right and you have to add the missing buttons or rename the code to make it compile successfully.

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort .. second, I'm sorry for the first errors on your list, I was trying to simplify my page and give a more meaningful names for you to understand but I miss typed some of them but I changed them now .. and last thing how come there's no errors on the Divs ? .. did you place all the mark of the TemplateMasterPage within the Content control (ContentArea) ?

Comment: You were like 90% Right .. and the rest of the errors where resolved by rebuilding the page .. there must have been an error with my compiler or something! .. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.